# Who executed that particular command on my centos VPS

Tags: security, centos

I have noticed that an unknown mysqldump command is being executed on my system. But I have not configured my system to issue that command. Following is the output when I do ps aux | grep mysqldump

```
500      28651  0.0  0.0   7892  1852 ?        Ss   00:26   0:01 /usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-extended-insert --allow-keywords --quote-names --compact --complete-insert --skip-lock-tables --quick --skip-comments --host=localhost --user=database_user --password=x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx database atable
```

500 is probably uid for my own user account (and only one that has bash access)

I have tried everything, like `last`, `history` and cron logs but unable to find the source.

How to find who is executing this particular command on my system?

**UPDATE**:
This is `getent passwd 500` output:

```
myusername:x:500:500::/home/myusername:/bin/bash
```

It happened again and now I have more info

This is `cat /proc/28126/status`

```
Name:   mysqldump
State:  S (sleeping)
SleepAVG:       98%
Tgid:   28126
Pid:    28126
PPid:   28108
TracerPid:      0
FNid:   10048627
Uid:    500     500     500     500
Gid:    500     500     500     500
FDSize: 64
Groups: 500 501
```

This is output for `ps auxf | grep mysqldump`

```
500      28126  0.0  0.0   7892  1852 ?        Ss   08:05   0:01          \_ /usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-extended-insert --allow-keywords --quote-names --compact --complete-insert --skip-lock-tables --quick --skip-comments --host=localhost --user=datebase_user --password=x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx database anothertable
```

UPDATE 2:
This is output for `ps aux | grep 28108`

```
500      28108  0.1  0.0  10504  2024 ?        S    08:05   0:04 sshd: myusername@notty
```

Oh, looks like someone has sshd but how to find the IP?

Comment: Check that uid please: getent passwd 500; Show us cat /proc/28651/status (Uid: Gid: and Groups: lines) and also look at parent of this process: ps auxf.

Comment: Please see update above. Basically 500 uid is my own useraccount (but I did not even touch the keyboard at that time). Since I restarted mysql to bring my site back, I can't run other commands...

Comment: It happened again, this time I have got more info... please see update above.

Comment: 28108 is the parent process.  what is that process?

Comment: @stew Show us more lines from ps command, use grep -C 5 mysqldump

Comment: @stew Updated question with more info regarding 28108 process, looks like someone sshd but who?

Comment: If you're trying to figure out the client IP of the ssh connection, run `netstat -pant` and look for ESTABLISHED ssh connections.

Comment: @cjc Thanks! I found the IP and it takes me to my backup company. I will ask them to stop playing with my server :)

Comment: Uh, don't you want them to back up your database, if they're a backup company?

Comment: @cjc Well for some reasons mysqldump will hang and lock all tables, and then eventually it brings my site down. I am in talks with them to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

`getent passwd 500` should tell you which user has uid 500.  Since the tty column is a ? it doesn't appear that it is attached to a particular login currently. (though that could mean that someone launched it interactively then `disown`ed it.

I'd wonder if you have a backup scheduled in cron which you don't know about.  You could check that user's crontab with `crontab -l -u username` or `cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username`, and check in directories like `/etc/cron.d` `/etc/cron.daily` `/etc/cron.hourly`

Comment: Its my own user account with that uid. Though I previously checked cron logs for any particular culprit and didn't find any but I will recheck.

Comment: Its not cron, I have updated my answer with more updates...

Answer (score 1):

add `--forest` to your `ps` command. This will show you parent/child relationships of all your processes. You should then just be able to walk up the tree until you find whats starting it.

Comment: oh I restarted again before I could run this command... but see more info above

Comment: Thanks, Patrick !  alias psf="ps --forest" just went into my .bashrc